# Sphinx search doesn't understand special characters (accents)

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have a MySQL db in utf8_general_ci.

And my sphinx.conf is like this:

```
source jobs
{
    type                = mysql
    sql_sock            = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8
    ...
}
```

When I query "système" I would like sphinx to search for "système" & "systeme" in the DB.

AND when I query "systeme" I would like sphinx to search for "système" & "systeme" too.

What it does now is removing all the characters before the accents (including the accents themselves). So "système" becomes "me" and "dév" becomes "v"...

*PS : I'm using the sphinxapi.php - which shouldn't be preferred over SphinxQL, I know, but it should still work with the api. And I use EXTENDED match mode.*

Comment: make sure that utf-8 is used THROUGHOUT the entire pipeline. it's pointless having a db connection and tables in utf8 if your php side of things is using (say) iso8859 for the user input side of things.

Comment: Header is set to UTF-8, html file too. My table is in UTF-8 and all the cols too. Everything is in UTF-8. Don't see where I can search for a possible trace of non-UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your `charset_table` to be able do this

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#charsets

Alas there is no 'magic' config option to just magically work with all languages text, need to setup charset_table to deal with the langauge(s) you deal with.

Although this is pretty close: 
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9312
(ie steals the hard work MySQL had done with collations and mimics it in charset_table)